# wrapping an asynchronous process in an akka actor

Tags: scala, akka

I'm dealing with a 3rd-party library which provides me with asynchronous method calls like this:

```
def doSomething1(input:String, callback:String => Any)
def doSomething2(input:Double, callback:String => Any)
```

The library is running stuff on some thread it creates.

I'd like to wrap an actor around it so I can `ask` it for junk, but I'm not sure how to get access to the `promise` so that I can fulfill the request.

The naive approach:

```
class Wrapper extends Actor {
  def receive {
    case s:String => doSomething1(s, sender ! _)
    case d:Double => doSomething2(d, sender ! _)
  }
}

val wrapper = system.actorOf(Props[Wrapper], "wrapper")
```

Then `ask` it for results:

```
(wrapper ? "hello").mapTo[String].foreach(println)
(wrapper ? 123.456).mapTo[String].foreach(println)
```

But the result never comes back, presumably because the callback isn't coming from the actor it `ask`ed.

Is there some way to get access to the `promise` so the callback can `success` it?

Comment: I can make it work by storing the sender, telling the callback to target the Wrapper, then have the Wrapper send the message back to the sender.

But now I'm wondering what happens if the messages come back out of order? How does it know how to match them up?

Comment: See my comment on @yan's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that I haven't tested this, but is this about what you're looking for?:

```
class Wrapper extends Actor {
  def receive = {
    case s : String =>
      val response = Promise[String]()
      val originator = sender
      doSomething1(s, response.success _)
      response.future.foreach(originator ! _)
    case d : Double =>
      val response = Promise[Double]()
      val originator = sender
      doSomething2(d, response.success _)
      response.future.foreach(originator ! _)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much yan, but I don't believe this helps. In my case, whatever thread the 3rd party library is running on is making the call, and in your case it's whatever thread is handling the Future, presumably the fork join pool. In neither case is the askee actor sending the response back.

Comment: @yan, I will assist here instead of answering myself because your answer is close.  The issue here is that you are closing over mutable state, namely the `sender` ref.  Under the line: `val response = Promise[String]()` I would add: `val originator = sender`.  Then tweak the `foreach` to: `response.future.foreach(originator ! _)`.  You could also use the `pipeTo` pattern from Akka instead and not have to deal with the whole closing over mutable state issue.

Comment: @cmbaxter: edited my original answer to your suggestion, thanks.